# Disable spellcheck on textarea when input is pasted

Tags: javascript, html

How do you disable spellcheck on a textarea if the user pastes their input? Spellcheck="false" only works if the user manually keys their input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a hack but to get it to work in Chrome you could do this:

```
<textarea spellcheck='false' onpaste="this.value=event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');return false;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nice hack, unfortunately the highlights appear briefly on the page before they disappear (clunky). I also want to address the scenario of when the user right-clicks and chooses paste.

Comment: I modified it to make it not clunky. It should also work when right click and pasting now.

Comment: This hack breaks the ability to select a specific snippet of text and then paste over that - it causes any paste to replace the entire contents of the textarea.

Comment: That broken functionality would be very annoying. I can't imagine this would be better than some squiggly lines. Also, wouldn't this be a bug in chrome?